# Caption format: Remove space between "Figure" and "1"

Tags: captions

everyone.

I would like to achieve a figure caption like this:

Figure1: Text.

I've read a lot of answers about caption format and I know how to change the text "Figure" but I still don't know how to remove the space between "Figure" and "1".

If anybody knows the answer I'll appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you have read a lot of answers you have seen most likely answers that are compilable. You're not providing something helpful to start yet :-( Please add a compilable document with `\documentclass`, the relevant packages and a working `\begin{document}...\end{document}` where a figure occurs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps this, redefining `\fnum@figure` to remove the `\nobreakspace` from its middle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\figurename{Figure}
\makeatletter
\def\fnum@figure{\figurename\thefigure}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\rule{1in}{1in}
\caption{This is a caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wanted to do it in only 1 location (not across the document), you could invoke `\let\nobreakspace\relax` inside the `figure` environment, prior to the `\caption`.

Comment: Steven, that worked just fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you very Much for the answer.